# Switching to the Existing Path When Drawing the New One Over It by Curvature tool in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Why when I use curvature tool and click on top of existing path, it not continues my current path but switches to this existing path?

Here is the illustration, not working example, just to show what I mean:

I try to continue the path over the existing one...
[image]

...but I cannot, Illustrator switches to this path!
[image]

I wasn't able to find the answer anywhere. The Pen tool working good: it's possible to make path on top of the existing one. So I have no problems when work with straight lines. But when creating the curved lines, as most designs and artworks have such parts, the Curvature tool is much more easy and useful. Except this extremely annoying problem.

The only solution I've found so far, is the creating new layer for the new path, and locking the layer where the existing path is. After that, I can use Curvature tool over the path, as I just cannot select it. But obviously, it's the complicated and time-consuming method.

May be the community can suggest the easy one? I believe Adobe predicted such problem and provided the option to disable the path switching when using Curvature tool.

Thank you!

Comment: Paths cannot intersect, they can only join. Any node can only have 2 paths coming out of it. To continue a path line, hover the pen tool over the endpoint until you see a little angled line. Click to start the next pen segment attached to the first path. It look like you want paths to cross. To do that draw a new path across the first path.

Answer (score 2):

Click(but do not release it) away from that path and drag to the desired place.

This will avoid the tool to switch to other objects.

Animated gif below:

[image]